# Better way to access Safari website data on iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, cookies

It is really irritating to have to *one at a time* delete hundreds of cookies/caches from websites I have never visited. (Would that Apple would allow us to block third-party cookies).

Is there an API that would allow me to build my own app in Xcode to handle it in a better way? Or something like Cookie 6 (macOS) for iOS? Or someone else’s open source that I can compile?

I’m not willing to jailbreak, nor to install something with source code not vetted by me or Apple.

For example, clearing all website data and then logging in to Facebook.com adds five third-party cookies.  Three of them are from domains owned by Facebook, but do not end in Facebook.com.  The other two are obviously from advertising services.

[image]

This is why I use DuckDuckGo for almost everything, and Safari only occasionally.  DuckDuckGo lets me clear everything after a session.  I use Safari for a few domains where I’d like to keep *their* cookies only, but the cost of that is consumption of storage space that doesn’t benefit me and prevents syncing all the music I’d like.

The cookies are less irritating than the consumption of limited storage space.  But if third-party cookies are accepted, cross-site tracking is implied.  Since I cleared **all** website data (recently), I have not visited any site with “math” in the name.  Only Facebook, UniGen.us, and three SE subdomains. Yet I have a cookie from mathoverflow.com  And Safari says it’s size is zero bytes.  Obviously, it is at least one byte.  But more of an issue are the megabytes of third-party local storage resulting in updates and Music syncs failing for insufficient space.

Comment: Can you add some examples of cookies you think Safari should block but apparently doesn't?

Comment: Please add the full names of these cookies and their domain, detail matter here.

Comment: I just tried in Chrome, with all cookies allowed, no blocking extentions etc, and all I got are seven FB cookies and some local storage. So please add a screenshots of what you got.

Comment: Well, Google owns Chrome, so they get what they want without invoking double click (which they also own).  The local storage is a bigger irritation than the tracking.  I guess I’ll just use DuckDuckGo (clearing all) on the iPad and for cookies I wanna keep, use the laptop where I have user-friendly control.

Comment: I rarely use Chrome so it was the easiest to check whether a FB login results in non-FB cookies (even DoubleClick should show up). But I doubt that FB will use DoubleClick anyway. Nevertheless it‘s hard to provide any specific answer to your Safari/Cookie problem unless you share specific details about the cookies you see.

Comment: Hmm.  I added a screen shot, but it’s not there now.  I will try to do it again. FB _did_ put a doubleclick item on my list and an atdmt.com, which by their size, could be cookies or local storage.  Either way, they’re cross-site.

Comment: Interesting. I only get fbcdn.net, facebook.com and fbsbx.com, not the other two. Do you have a homepage set in Safari which loads as soon as you start it? Anyway, 1Blocker is available for iOS and should block whatever Safari doesn't catch.

Comment: 1Blocker is worth checking out, thanks

Comment: double click.net is owned by google

Answer (score 0):

Safari already blocks third-party cookies by default. Check yours is in Settings → Safari → Prevent Cross-Site Tracking.

There are no APIs for interacting with data from the Safari app, only for web views within the app itself. Therefore there’s nothing third party apps can do without jailbreaking.

Comment: If they are blocked, how the (censored) do I have them from at least a hundred domains I have never visited?

Comment: I cleared all website data, then opened Safari, logged into Facebook, and dismissed Safari without clicking anything.  Website data then included items from Google, double click, and atdmt, plus sixteen megabytes from five domains owned by Facebook.  Visiting stack exchange and turning off all but “essential cookies,” without logging in, stores megabytes more on the iPad, most of them from NSA’s competitor (Google)

Comment: And cross-site tracking has been denied for a long time.

Comment: @WGroleau Check if you have disabled Safari syncing on iCloud and disabled iCloud Tabs ( https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202530 ).

Comment: Safari has always been off for iCloud, but I doubt that has anything to do with cookies stored locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a user it is very infuriating that Apple does not allow other browsers on `ios` / `iPadOS` with better privacy features (all browsers on ios have to use `Safari`'s Webkit rendering engine, and thus all of them suffer from similar limitations).

To better safeguard your privacy on ios / iPadOS, I recommend the following -

1. Disable `Safari` on `iCloud`.
2. Install [**AdGuard**](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-ios/overview.html) and,
3. Enable [**Private Browsing** on Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203036).

**Pros** of this approach:

1. `Adguard` is designed to blocks ads and trackers on `Safari` in an Apple approved safe manner.
2. Since most of the ad and tracker scripts are blocked, websites load faster. And when they are blocked, they can't install their unwanted cookies too.
3. By using *Private Browsing* mode on `Safari`, you ensure that whenever you close `Safari`, or any Tab on `Safari`, *all* website data (including cookies) is deleted immediately.
4. Preventing `Safari` from syncing to `iCloud` prevents previous (or other device) [`Safari` website data from being loaded into `Safari` on your ios, from `iCloud`](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202530).

**Cons**:

1. On rare occasions, some websites don't work properly when ads and / or trackers are blocked. This is rare, but `Safari` provides an easy fix - it has an option to [reload the website again without any content blocking](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/disable-content-blockers-safari-ios/).
2. In *Private Browsing* mode, no history or auto-fill information is saved. Moreover, since it deletes all websites data, you cannot be always logged in.
3. Some ad networks hate *Private browsing* mode. Websites that use them will thus sometimes show banners / pop-ups blocking the site partially. `Adguard` takes care of most of these annoyances, but some still slip through. (I have noticed this mostly on large online media sites).

I find this approach as a good compromise on convenience vs privacy on the `ios` platform.

---

If you want build and customise your own browser for ios, `Firefox Focus` is a decent open source browser you can use for your project - [source code for Firefox Focus for iOS](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-ios) is available on Github.

Comment: Seems worth a try.  But are you claiming that the tor browser (SLOW) and DuckDuckGo (not slow) are lying about their privacy features?

Comment: On ios / iPadOS platform, any tor browser is forced to use Safari's rendering engine, and thus cannot provide the same level of privacy features as the Tor desktop on the desktop. They do warn you about this - https://support.torproject.org/tormobile/tormobile-3/ .

Comment: About Duckduckgo, I can't honestly say. Google pays Apple around $15 billion dollars to be the default search engine in ios. So why would Apple provide DuckDuckGo on ios without any stakes? Duckduckgo incorporates Apple maps in its search indicating a business relationship with them. Personally, I believe both Google and DDG share some search data with Apple. Apple needs these data to better profile us and to improve their products (e.g. like Siri). Note that **this is speculation** - we really don't know the agreement that Google and DDG have with Apple, and it depends on local privacy laws.

Comment: I would guess that DuckDuckGo links to Apple Maps because Apple is less nosy than Google or Bing.  Then again, we don’t really know what’s in DuckDuckGo.  It’s quite possible NSA created it, and the claims of privacy are a smokescreen.  :-)  I don’t think so, but it’s possible.

Comment: Private browsing is a fair compromise.  But I’d really prefer to have a way to pick and choose instead of all or nothing, or to pick one at a time from a HUGE list.I might look at Focus.  But I’ve had a lot less motivation for coding since I retired and found other things more fun.  :-)

Comment: I did install AdGuard.  I’ll be checking how it changes things…

Comment: AdGuard is an improvement, but it fails to block doubleclick.net  But its customization options are also worth exploring.

Comment: As adblockers work against ads and trackers, advertisers fight against them and continually change their tactics that sometimes allow them to temporarily bypass the adblockers. If some ad or tracker slips through AdGuard, please post about it here - https://forum.adguard.com/index.php?forums/missed-ads.67/ - and they'll update the filters.

Comment: I'd love to have something similar to Cookie 5 on MacOS.  It allowed me to say which domain names were allowed to store cookies.  Only way to get around that would be to change your domain name.

Comment: Note though that even if AdGuard misses a cookie, Safari *private browsing* will ensure 2 things - (1) that the cookie is available only for Safari Tab that created it and it won't be shared with any other websites you have opened & (2) As soon as the Safari Tab is closed the cookies are destroyed. A cookie is used for tracking and is only useful if it can be accessed again or is persistent in the device.

Comment: I reported the issue to AdGuard by e-mail, because their webform is disabled without a version number, which I can’t find anywhere in the app settings or the iPad settings.