# Precisely what does "Allow app to track your activity across other companies' apps and websites" mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, security

It's a great step in the right direction that iOS 14.7.1 now forces apps to let the user know that it's tracking their activity, with a prompt such as this:

[image]

It says:

> Track your activity across other companies' apps and websites

which is vague, and doesn't state what 'Allow' actually gives the app access to. For example, I am not sure if it will grant the app access to:

- All Safari activity?
- Search history and activity on *other* browsers (e.g. chrome)?
- Activity on *the current* device only, or **all devices**?
- *All* other apps on that device, or just some? (and if it's a subset, can I look up which ones?)
- **Past** activity (e.g. search history), or *just* future activity?

#### Publicly available information is also vague

- The Apple website page '[About iOS 14 Updates](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT211808)' states:

> App Tracking Transparency lets you control which apps are allowed to track your activity across other companies' apps and websites for ads or sharing with data brokers

and

> and App Tracking Transparency lets you control which apps are allowed to track your activity across other companies' apps and websites

this also does not give precise delineation between what is being allowed and not allowed.

- Apple's page on [(if) an app asks to track your activity](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT212025) states:

> Tracking occurs when information that identifies you or your device collected from an app is linked with information that identifies you or your device collected on apps, websites and other locations owned by third parties for the purposes of targeted advertising or advertising measurement, or when the information collected is shared with data brokers.

and links to [a privacy info page](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT211970) that states:

> including location, contact info, health info and more

But it too doesn't mention how to find which apps this prompt gives an app permission to share with, nor whether it allows sharing of **all** browser activity or just the activity on third party websites which share trackers with the app in question.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation about this on Apple‘s and other websites, have you done some research there? What have you found and what remains unclear?

Comment: @nohillside updated

Comment: I'd assume everything is being tracked, because it probably is regardless of what anything/anyone says!  BBIW

Comment: The screenshot you‘ve included is from DoorDash, this is about tracking within that app. Safari doesn’t play a role here.

Comment: @nohillside hmmm the prompt literally says "across **other companies'** apps and websites". Since safari is another company's app, that indicates that safari activity could indeed be tracked.

Comment: The reason you're misunderstanding this is that you're interpreting allow to be granting additional access. This is not the case. Clicking Allow grants the previous status-quo level of access. Not clicking allow is the new option.

Comment: It is true that Safari *could* play a roll here - but it does not. Safari is unrelated to this prompt. Clicking Allow doesn't change the privacy settings of your phone, otherwise it would indicate that. Any "other company" would have it in their terms of agreement that they might share your data.

Comment: Tracking is done with tracking links/pixels basically, so if you allow apps A and B to track you and also use any browser to access a website which uses the same tracking as A and B then you can be tracked across A, B and the website by the tracking provider.

Comment: @nohillside, sounds like you have the knowledge to write the answer.  If you do, you might include a mention of “third-party cookies.”  I’ve been told Safari never allows them, but my local storage contains a _huge_ quantity of domain names that I have NEVER visited.

Comment: @WGroleau Maybe these third-party cookies in Safari are old/got created before Apple allowed to block cross-site tracking? Or they are not considered harmful by Apple?

Comment: I frequently delete them.  But it's a proctalgia to have to do one at a time, several clicks each.  Tracking or not, it irritates me to see NSA's biggest competitor more than a dozen times in the list.  (No, I do NOT use Google for web searches.)

Comment: @WGroleau Might be worth its own question, actually (make sure to include a screenshots of some cookies including their domain if you do). This one here is about ATT, I'll add an answer later.

Comment: @nohillside: The 'other question' already exists: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423956/better-way-to-access-safari-website-data-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

This gives the unique identifier of your device to the app. For example, apps could sell your usage patterns linked with the ID to a database, and advertisers can use these patterns to advertise relevant ads to this specific device. Blocking this is generally good, since it allows you to prevent more personalized data to be sent to data collectors and advertisers. Some companies, such as google (if you don’t have a google account), have gotten around this by using your usage patterns as your identifier itself (since there AI is so sophisticated).